# How to set and get values in local storage with .jar (in Drupal 7)?

Tags: javascript, java, drupal, jar, drupal-7

I've been tasked to create a module that requires and me to set and get variables in local storage. I cannot use PHP's cookies. The example code I've been pointed to simply has the line:

```
Drupal.Jar.setItem('email', $('.user__email').val());
```

I'm guessing this sets a value, taken from the DOM, in local storage. But how do I then retrieve that value? I tried searching online but didn't come up with any documentation around `.Jar` or `Drupal.Jar`.

As a test, I tried adding the below to my .js file (guessing that `getItem()` would be used to retrieve the value:

```
Drupal.Jar.setItem('test', $('.some-div').val());
var testitem = Drupal.Jar.getItem('test');
console.log('testitem: ' + testitem);
```

But this returns nothing (no errors either).

Would anyone know what I can do to set and get a value with Jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in Java .jar implementation in Drupal 7.

I'm guessing the example code is from a custom module's javascript using `Drupal.Jar` as a namespace.

If you have the full code (and the dependencies) perhaps you can modify it to your needs.

Or if you or going to create your javascript from scratch, you may wanna check out MDN documentation for [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: You're right - it did turn out to be from a custom module I was unaware of.